# Count statement not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get a list of records that have a specific value. I only want it to retrieve however if there's over 10. My current solution

```
SELECT attr1
FROM table
WHERE attr2 = 'value1'
GROUP BY attr1
HAVING count(*) > 10
```

There are 12 records that show `value1` so in theory, it should show up. It only shows up if I change the count to `9`, is there something wrong with my statement? I've tried adding records but does not work. Thanks

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: To answer, people are going to need more information. I think I see some of the problem, however. Do you understand how `GROUP BY` works? You're saying that there are 12 records "that show `value1`." If, by that, you mean that there are 12 occurrences of `value1` in your table in the `attr2` field, look at the corresponding values in `attr1`. Your query requires that there be more than 10 occurrences of the pair consisting of the value in `attr1` and `value1` in `attr2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1.
There are no 10 value1 records **per attr1**

Option 2.
You have white characters in your text.
Use `hex(attr2)` to find them